# How can I verify if the subtitles on the Chrome default player are appearing and in what language they are appearing using C# nunit Selenium,

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, automation, nunit

How can I verify if the subtitles on the Chrome default player are appearing and in what language they are appearing using C# nunit Selenium, please help

I have tried try catch but it's not working.
how can i find the button in the video element in the DOM

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.